# ajax jquery settings

Tags: ajax, jquery

So say I want to import (using ajax) a script which contains both some raw html and a java script:

```
<p>To comment, please first prove that you are human being</p>
<form method='post' action='../recapatcha_verify.php'>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=your_public_key">
 </script>
<input type='submit'/> 
</form>
```

is there anything wrong with the following function?

```
  function comments(file, id, fs, pn, ln)
   {
      $("div#commentWrapper").show(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "../commentfiles/" + file,
           pid: id,
           fs: fs,
           pn: pn,
           ln: ln,
           dataType: script,
           success: function(txt)
                 {
            $("div#commentWindow").html(txt);
                  }
       });
      });

      }
```

`pid` `fs` `pn` and `ln` are supposed to be parameters in the url. This works when i use the `$.get` method, but does it work the same for $.ajax??

I set datatype to "script" so that the javascript would be recognized. But is this correct? I'm not sure I know what I'm doing yet.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions, no, `$.ajax` does not take parameters the same way as `$.get`. To send parameters, you must use `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {param1: 1, param2: 2, param3: 3},
    ...
});
```

Secondly, right now you're setting `dataType` to the value of a variable named `script`. You must set it to the string `script`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'script',
    ...
});
```

Some other things:

1. You may want to explicitly specify it's a `GET` request using `type: 'GET'`.
2. If it's HTML that contains a script, `script` is the wrong data type. (`script` will try to evaluate the HTML as JavaScript, which won't work)
3. `.html` will indeed insert the `script` tag, but it won't execute it. To get it to execute, you must remove and then re-insert the `script` tag.

Comment: well how do I set a data type for something that is partially "html" and partially a "script"?

Comment: @Jeff: Your `success` callback is expecting a string, so you'd set it to `text`.